# Android back button doesn't navigate back correctly

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

When clicking the back button, the app completely closes, instead of going back one activity in the back stack. How come?

To clarify:

**A --> B** - App launches and user clicks on a button that starts another activity.

**A <-- B** - User clicks back button and goes back to previous activity (this is what I expected to happen).

**<-- B**  - User clicks back button and app completely closes (what actually happens).

Could it possibly be my manifest file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that you probably started activity A with finish at the end. For example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Take a look more about back navigation on android developer documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html).

Comment: Another thing that could be, that you have declared noHistory for your activity A in the manifest. Then it is not saved in the activity stack.

Comment: I've used exactly that piece of code. Currently looking in the documentation you linked to.

Comment: If you call finish(), you kill the activity and it is removed from the activity stack. That is why you can't navigate back to it.

Comment: As Robert K. said, try to remove finish.

Comment: Nice, that did it. What is the reason one would call finish() after starting an activity? I though finish() was needed to start the activity, something like calling a commit function.

Comment: Good!. In case that you want to close previous activity :) Why to keep let's say splash screen in stack... Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not your Manifest. The Activity 'A' is Finished which only happens at `intent`.

Also, Check what is happening when you press Back Button while you are in Activity B.